# How would you interpret the carry of 10 + 10 in binary?

Tags: cpu

When doing stacked addition, 1+1 = 10, meaning the sum is 0 and the carry is one, when you have 1+1 and a carry with 1, the sum is 1 and the carry is one, So the carry seems to be the first digit, and the sum is always the second. But what would 1+1+1+1 be?

Comment: `100` answered at [Binary multiplication how to carry a 001 in case of adding 4 times 1? - Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1779837/binary-multiplication-how-to-carry-a-001-in-case-of-adding-4-times-1)

Comment: None of the columns in a binary number are a "carry" column, just as none of the columns in a normal number is used for carry information. "Carry" is a temporary idea used when you overflow the current column and need to add a digit to the next column. You might want to learn [how to read binary numbers](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-read-binary-4692830).

Answer (score 0):

```
1 + 1 = 10
1 + 1 + 1 = 11
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 100
```

Or, if you want to cheat a bit, 1 in binary is the same as 1 in decimal, so in decimal 1+1+1+1 = 4.     4 in binary is 1^2 + 0^1 + 0^1  = 100

```
   0  
   1
  10
  11
 100  <----- 4th digit in sequence
 101
 110
 111
1000
1001
1010
1011
1100
1101
1110
1111
|||+------- goes 0,1 (repeat)   
||+-------- goes 0,0,1,1  (repeat)
|+--------- goes 0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1  (repeat)
+---------- goes 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 (repeat)
```